# "The Apple Store app is not available in your country or region" after Apple Store update on iPad

Tags: ipad, ios-appstore

After Apple Store update I've got "The Apple Store app is not available in your country or region", and my country is missing from the list (it's Ukraine). Just in case I have iPad Air 2020.

On my iPhone though no updates were requested and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing was that I just have confused App Store and Apple Store apps, and there was no real issue. Just delete the Apple Store app from your device if you don't have an official Apple store in your country.